# Event reminders with Google App Script not triggering at the right time

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-calendar-api

I volunteer with an animal rescue and we are mostly virtual, sometimes volunteers forget to attend the meeting so i wanted a 12 hr reminder and a 15 min reminder and this is the code that i got

The trigger is time driven, i tried an hr, 5 mins, 10 mins etc; and currently its set to the latter I got 75 email reminders last night about an event that is at 12:30 PST

It looks as though the trigger is sending an email at that moment of the trigger rather than sticking to the script schedule, is there a way around it?

Thanks

```
function sendEventReminder() {
  var calendarName = 'vol@sanctuaryhostel.org'; // Replace with the name of your Google Calendar
  var eventName = 'Chatgpt Event'; // Replace with the name of the specific event

  var now = new Date();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];

  if (!calendar) {
    Logger.log("Calendar not found.");
    return;
  }

  var events = calendar.getEvents(now, new Date(now.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    if (event.getTitle() === eventName) {
      sendEmailReminder(event.getTitle(), event.getStartTime(), event.getGuestList(), calendarName);
      break; // Exit the loop after sending the reminder for this event
    }
  }
}

function sendEmailReminder(eventTitle, eventStartTime, eventGuests, hostEmail) {
  var intervals = [{ minutesBefore: 720, label: '12 hours' }, { minutesBefore: 30, label: '30 minutes' }];
  var subject = 'Reminder: Upcoming Event - ' + eventTitle;
  var bodyBase = 'This is a reminder for the upcoming event:\n\n' +
             'Event: ' + eventTitle + '\n' +
             'Date and Time: ' + eventStartTime;

  var allRecipients = eventGuests.map(function(guest) {
    return guest.getEmail();
  });
  allRecipients.push(hostEmail);

  var now = new Date();

  for (var i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
    var interval = intervals[i];
    var body = bodyBase + '\nReminder: ' + interval.label + ' before the event';
    var reminderTime = new Date(eventStartTime.getTime() - (interval.minutesBefore * 60 * 1000));

    // Send reminder only if the reminder time is in the future
    if (now < reminderTime) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: allRecipients.join(','),
        subject: subject,
        body: body
      });
      break; // Exit the loop after sending the reminder
    }
  }
}
function sendEmailReminder(eventTitle, eventStartTime, eventGuests, hostEmail) {
  var intervals = [{ minutesBefore: 720, label: '12 hours' }, { minutesBefore: 30, label: '30 minutes' }];
  var subject = 'Reminder: Upcoming Event - ' + eventTitle;
  var bodyBase = 'This is a reminder for the upcoming event:\n\n' +
             'Event: ' + eventTitle + '\n' +
             'Date and Time: ' + eventStartTime;

  var allRecipients = eventGuests.map(function(guest) {
    return guest.getEmail();
  });
  allRecipients.push(hostEmail);

  var now = new Date();

  for (var i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
    var interval = intervals[i];
    var body = bodyBase + '\nReminder: ' + interval.label + ' before the event';
    var reminderTime = new Date(eventStartTime.getTime() - (interval.minutesBefore * 60 * 1000));

    Logger.log('Now: ' + now);
    Logger.log('Reminder Time: ' + reminderTime);

    // Send reminder only if the reminder time is in the future
    if (now < reminderTime) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: allRecipients.join(','),
        subject: subject,
        body: body
      });
      break; // Exit the loop after sending the reminder
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use gmailApp to send email reminders.   I  noticed that you have two functions with same name.  Every function in a project must have a unique name.